# Putting a full stop in the end of an equation makes equation number appear one line below

Tags: equations, numbering, line-breaking, punctuation

I'm having a problem. I am writing my thesis in physics, so I use a lot of equations. Since equations are to be treated as part of a sentence they include punctuation in the end. I have all the equations numbered, but punctuation makes the equation number appear on a new line. I use the following code to introduce equations into the paper:

```
\begin{equation}

\label{ix}

\centerline{$I_{aligned} = I - I_{rot}$.}

\end{equation}
```

This makes equations appear as follows:

[image]

But I want the equation number to be on the same line as the equation.

Comment: Don't use `\centerline`.  The `equation` environment is already centered.  Also, you can't have blank lines inside the `equation` environment.  Finally, use `I_\mathrm{aligned}`, as the "aligned" is a word (or acronym) and not a math variable.  Likewise on "rot".

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that. Thank you! That solved it. Now to change 140 pages of equations!

Comment: Don't you just hate it when that happens??

Comment: you need a very good regex search/replace `;-)` for your 140 pages ...

Comment: Welcome, you could have asked the question a bit earlier to save some time replacing stuff ;-)

Comment: It would be annoying to just use a replace function, because of }$ or }.$ in the end of every center line that needs removing too. And this will appear in in-paragraph equations too potentially. And haha, yes, I should have definitely asked earlier. Thanks for the help anyhow!

Comment: I hope you don't really have blank lines in your `equation` environment.

Answer (score 4):

The presence of the full stop is not relevant at all. You get exactly the same effect with

```
\begin{equation}
\centerline{$a=b$}
\end{equation}
```

and

```
\begin{equation}
\centerline{$a=b$}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The fact is that the input is wrong to begin with: `\centerline` is a Plain TeX macro and should not be used in LaTeX, unless *very special* effects are needed.

An `equation` environment already centers the math material without any further effort. So your input should be

```
\documentclass{article} % this class just for producing the example

\usepackage{amsmath} % for math typesetting

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{ix}
I_{\textup{aligned}} = I - I_{\textup{rot}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that blank lines are not allowed inside `equation` and that the textual subscript should be in the upright font.

[image]